# Is there a way to make the [UP| key show the most recent command in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

On the Linux virtual machine I'm using, whenver I press the up-key I get this :

```
^[[A
```

But what I want is for it to do like the Mac , which is to show the most recent command or text I entered into the terminal.

thanks!

Comment: Whatever SQL client you are using in the screen shot does not support what you are asking.  Find another one or see if you can recompile it with something like `readline` support.

Comment: -1 for the screenshot alone.

Comment: @tripleee - thanks , I think readline support is what  is referenced in answer below? i.e `rlwrap` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those cases I always use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/).

Almost for sure, your Linux distribution already has some package with this tool. For example, Debian: [rlwrap wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/rlwrap)

EDIT

Another nice link I've just found where you can see how to use rlwrap with SQL*Plus: [rlwrap and SQL*Plus](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rlwrap.htm).